# Save Firebase database into Array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

How to save my below firebase data response into 2-arrays one of categories & another for sub-categories ?

```
 {
 "category-1" =     {
    name = sub1;
    name2 = sub2;
 };
 "category-2" =     {
    name = sub3;
    name2 = sub4;
 };
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create an object for categories so that you can create the array of them.

```
struct Category {
    name: String?
    name2: String?
}
```

Once you can create the object using your data from Firebase, you can create an array of them like:

```
var categories = [Category]()
categories.append(someCategory)
```